# Get every 100th value in a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, syntax

Is there a way to make this cleaner and not use the tempvalue like i have done here?

---

UPDATE the  code had a logic bug and didn't show what I'm doing.
This is what I'm doing:

```
var loopTempValue = noOfPackets / 100;
for(i=0; i < noOfPackets; i++)
{   
    \\DoStuff

    if (i == loopTempValue)
    {
         loopTempValue = loopTempValue + (noOfPackets / 100);
         UploadBackGroundWorker.ReportProgress(pross);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE Final

This is how its fixed after the feedback, thx guys.

```
if (i % (noOfPackets / 100) == 0 && i != 0)
{
     UploadBackGroundWorker.ReportProgress(pross);
}
```

Comment: have you ever heard about `<something>=` operators? they replace statements like `a = a <something> b` with `a <something>= b`. E.g.: `a += b`, `a %= b`, `a *= 2`...

Comment: To be clear, you want the 36, 72, 144, ... sequence as in your code or th 100,200, 300 sequence form the title?

Comment: updated code,, first contained a logic error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if (i % 100 == 0 && i != 0) { //YOUR CODE }
```

Modulus is fantastic for checks like this.

More on Modulus - http://www.vias.org/cppcourse/chap04_01.html

UPDATE: I added `&& i != 0` for the 0 case being true.

If you want to use the tempvalue instead of hard coding 100, then this would be a solution:

```
if (i % tempvalue == 0 && i != 0) { //YOUR CODE }
```

Comment: you're mising the tempvalue (which is important here)

Comment: And this is `true` for `i==0` as well.

Comment: @Casper: Well, he stated: "Is there a was to make this cleaner and not use the tempvalue like i have done here". So I assumed he didn't want to use it at all.

Comment: @rara: it's not a lineair sequence

Comment: This answers the Title-question but is nowhere near the code sample.

Comment: @Darkmake: According to your update, this is not what you needed. It will trigger 35 times during the loop, but you want it to trigger 100 times during the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You mean that you want the condition to be triggered 100 times during the loop, i.e. every 36th iteration? (In your original code you double the tempvalue each time, so it would only trigger seven times during the loop.)

You can use the modulo operator to check for that. This will trigger the condition at the last of each set of 36 iterations:

```
for(i=0; i < 3600; i++) {
   \\DoStuff

   if(i % 36 == 35) {
      \\DoStuff
   }
}
```

Comment: yeah thx for pointing out the bug, i dident think it trough enough when writing the exsample

Answer (score 1):

```
if( (i+1 % (tempvalue+1) == 0)
{
      //DoStuff

      //tempvaule = tempvalue + tempvalue;
}
```