# Print message every 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plugins

Modifying a plugin for a Rust game server, and I'm not too great at C#. I currently have the system set up to print the votes to chat every time a new vote comes in, but want it based on percentage or every 5 votes. How would I do that? This is my current code.

```
       public int tallyVotes() {
        int yesVotes = 0;
        foreach (var votes in votesReceived) {
            if (votes.Value)
                yesVotes = yesVotes + 1;
        }
        return yesVotes;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get every 100 vaule in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792682/get-every-100-vaule-in-a-loop)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518680/for-statement-each-1000th-walkthrough-do-something

Comment: logically are you saying you do not know how to capture the `yesVotes` and check if the `yesVotes == 5` if so the print the message and rest the `yesVotes Counter...?`

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you return yesVotes/5 as an integer, essentially giving you 1 vote for every 5.

```
int voteWeighting = 5;    
return (int)yesVotes/voteWeighting;
```

if you're looking for when to print it then the generic fizz buzz solution would fix it.

```
int printWeighting = 5;
if (yesVotes%printWeighting ==0)
{
//print stuff here
}
```

this works by using the modulus function "a%b" it will return the remainder when you divide a by b and as such return a number less than "b" but greater or equal to zero. as such if you only ever increment by 1 the number, then when a mod b is 0 you have incremented b times.

[Fizzbuzz example](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest)